# AWS SES template from Cloudformation / serverless

Tags: aws-cloudformation, amazon-ses, serverless-framework

I'm using the [serverless framework](https://serverless.com) to deploy my AWS stacks, and I’m trying to add an AWS SES template to my resources.

However, I keep getting “unrecognized type” from CloudFormation for `AWS::SES::Template`.

This is definitely a [defined CloudFormation resource type](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-resource-ses-template.html), so I don’t know what’s going on. I've seen identical snippets describing SES templates that supposedly work, but for me it doesn't. Any ideas what could be causing this?

The section in my `serverless.yml` looks like this:

```
resources:
  Resources:
    EmailNotificationTemplate:
      Type: AWS::SES::Template 
      Properties: 
        Template: 
          TemplateName: "test" 
          TextPart: "body text" 
          SubjectPart: "subject"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turns out this was due to SES not being available in the region I was using. It sure would've been nice with a error message such as "type not supported in region", but instead the generic "unrecognized type" was raised.

Comment: Any way to specify the region just for that resource?

Comment: Does not seem like it - the entire SLS provider must be in the same region afaik. I ended up creating a separate stack for SES only and placed it in a suitable region.